# Iterating through every column name in a table one at a time

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a series of excel documents all with different structures that i am trying to import into a SQL database. The solution i have come up with is to get the user to map the columns in the spreadsheet with the columns in the database. The problem i am having is getting the database column names one at a time, i can get them all at once with the following SQL command in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but i can for the life of me get it to iterate through them and i have no idea how i would translate this to vb.net.

```
SELECT [name] AS [Column Name]
FROM syscolumns
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND [Name] = 'table1')
```

I currently have the user selecting the spreadsheet column from a Listbox and i want the database column to appear in a Label above it so when the user hits next i can just reset the Listbox and move to the next database column while mapping the two column names in a two dimensional array.

Comment: What are you doing in vb to try and iterate through the columns?

Comment: Do you want to do it in vb.net? Give more information. What do you want to accomplish. Where do you want the columns to be iterated through? And why do you want to use vb.net?

Comment: i have tried to use a TableAdapter but didn't get it to work, so basically im at a complete loss so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I give you C# code, will you be able to translate?

Comment: i can give it a go, im using vb.net as the rest of the project is written in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("<your connection string>)"))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from table1)", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    reader.GetName(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: ok i can get everything to work except the part where you have put // Debug.WriteLn(read["name"].ToString());

I cant find anyway to translate that.

Comment: I've just added it there. That is where you will populate your combo. The syntax is probably wrong anyway. It is just a comment

Comment: thanks for your help i managed to figure it out, ill post the answer i came up with below.

Comment: I thought I gave you the answer. It is just good manners to accept an answer from somebody that helped you

Comment: sorry buddy i was getting around to that, i just wanted to post my answer as well and again thanks for your help.

Comment: No Problem. Sometimes people post their own answers and then mark them as the correct answer. Sorry if I was to quick on the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.UK_DATABASE_2014ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from table1;", conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If i >= reader.FieldCount Then
                Return True
            Else
                Label1.Text = reader.GetName(i)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: Fix your for loop. In reader you have reader.FieldCount, then you don't need the if or exit

Comment: It looks like great minds think a like, i had just noticed that and fixed it with FieldCount :)